# Replace with a newline

Tags: newlines, geany

[Geany](http://geany.org/), like many text editors, has a *replace* dialog:

[image: Geany replace]

In the `Replace with:` field, how can I express that I want the pattern to get replaced with a new line character?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### How can I express that I want the pattern to get replaced with a new line character?

- Set "Replace with" to `\n`
- Enable "Use regular expressions"
- Enable "Use multi-line matching"

---

#### Regular expression syntax

[image]

Source [Regular expression syntax](http://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-regex-syntax.html)

Comment: Note: if you have literal "\n" strings in a file and need them replaced with newlines, first do a non-regex replace of "\n" with something like "ThisIsANewLine", and then do the regex replace of "ThisIsANewLine" with "\n"

Comment: @SteveDonie If you have a literal "\\n" to replace it is easier to just escape the "\" using "\\n"

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer did not work for me. What did work was checking 'Use escape sequences,' then using the '\n' in the replace field.

This was using Geany 0.21 which did not have "Use multi-line matching."

After updating Geany to 1.30.1 which does have "Use multi-line matching" the selected answer should work.

Comment: What version and platform? Both methods worked for me (Geany 1.36 (2020-03-22) on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) base with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment))).

Comment: Can you [add it](https://superuser.com/posts/1558182/edit) to the answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar)?